# One to One relationship in a database

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, database-design

I'm currently working with the [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) Framework and I have noticed something that is making me question the design of my database.

I currently have the following table `products` where each record represents a product, and it contains a foreign key to a `prices` table, representing the price/currency associated with the product.

```
+-----------+---------+----------+-----+-----------+
|product_id |price_id |seller_id |title|description|
+--------------------------------------------------+
|           |         |          |     |           |
|           |         |          |     |           |
|           |         |          |     |           |
|           |         |          |     |           |
+-----------+---------+----------+-----+-----------+
```

Now I'm looking at the Laravel documentation that describes relationships between models [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships). The transitive verb I would use in this relationship is that a `Product` **has a** `Price`. However, according to the Laravel documentation, I need to use the "belongsTo" rather than the "hasOne" function (ie. Product belongsTo Price). This functions properly, but using the wrong transitive verb seems a little odd and less readable, which is why I'm questioning my database design.

In order to use the "hasOne" relationship in Laravel, I must reverse the direction of the foreign key, and instead have the `prices` table have a foreign key to which the product the price is associated with.

**products table:**

```
+-----------+----------+-----+-----------+
|product_id |seller_id |title|description|
+----------------------------------------+
|           |          |     |           |
|           |          |     |           |
|           |          |     |           |
|           |          |     |           |
+-----------+----------+-----+-----------+
```

**prices table:**

```
+-----------+----------+------+----------+
|price_id   |product_id|amount|currency  |
+----------------------------------------+
|           |          |      |          |
|           |          |      |          |
|           |          |      |          |
|           |          |      |          |
+-----------+----------+------+----------+
```

Which design is the correct design? To me it makes more sense to have a `price_id` column in the `products` table so you can immediately see that a `product` is associated with a `price` when looking at the table. It also seems more efficient because you are looking up the price by it's primary index, rather than looking up the price by looking up the product_id column.

Comment: The way they are making you do it a product can have multiple prices and a product can have no price. Seems wrong to me

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your business rules are.  In most cases, `price` would be an attribute of `product`.  In other words, the price is just a column on the product table.

There may be complications on this simple scenario.

For example, you may have different prices for the same product, depending on for example, who you're selling it to.  Or you might be storing the changing history of prices for a product over time.  In this case, you have a one:many relationship (one `product` has many `prices`).

On the other hand, you may have a more specialized case, like selling packages of small pieces of hardware or some kind of dry goods that are sold by weight.  Think of going to Home Depot and seeing little blister packs with prices like "$AA", "$BB" where these symbols translate into some number of dollars and cents which will vary over time.  In this case, you have a one:many in the other direction, i.e. one `price` has many `products`.

The important thing to remember in this scenario is that you wouldn't do it this way unless you deliberately mean to change all prices in lock-step.  If everything that costs $1.50 is changing price at one time to $1.55, then this second scenario might be right.

What you should **never** do is link child records to a single parent record when that relationship is coincidental.  In other words, just because product A and product B happen to have an equal price, that equality could be *coincidental* and so you shouldn't be taking the price out of the product table and making a price table, just because some things coincidentally share a price.

To be able to answer your question, you need to start by figuring out exactly what your business rules are and more specifically, how many prices does each product have and are the prices of different products related in a meaningful way or a coincidental way.  This will help you drive you data model and from there your Laravel verbs will follow sensibly.